# C# Reflection get Field or Property by Name

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, null-coalescing-operator

Is there a way to supply a name to a function that then returns the value of either the field or property on a given object with that name? I tried to work around it with the null-coalesce  operator, but apparently that doesn't like different types (which is also a bit weird to me because null is null). I could separate it it out into if nulls, but there has to be a better way to do this. Here is my function, and the two lines with `Comparison` objects don't compile, but I will leave them in there to show what I am trying to do.

```
private void SortByMemberName<T>(List<T> list, string memberName, bool ascending)
{
   Type type = typeof (T);
   MemberInfo info = type.GetField(memberName) ?? type.GetProperty(memberName);

   if (info == null)
   {
        throw new Exception("Member name supplied is neither a field nor property of type " + type.FullName);
   }

   Comparison<T> asc = (t1, t2) => ((IComparable) info.GetValue(t1)).CompareTo(info.GetValue(t2));
   Comparison<T> desc = (t1, t2) => ((IComparable) info.GetValue(t2)).CompareTo(info.GetValue(t1));

    list.Sort(ascending ? asc : desc);
}
```

I have heard of something called dynamic LINQ that could be used, but for the sake of learning, I am doing it my way.

Comment: The null coalescing operator doesnt work because a `FieldInfo` is not a `PropertyInfo`. Use `as` to cast them.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Change this line:

```
MemberInfo info = type.GetField(memberName) ?? type.GetProperty(memberName);
```

to this:

```
MemberInfo info = type.GetField(memberName) as MemberInfo ??
    type.GetProperty(memberName) as MemberInfo;
```

because there's no implicit cast to the base class when using the ternary operator like that. The ternary requires that the types of all outputs be the same.

Comment: That's not the ternary operator, it's the null-coalescing operator.

Comment: Besides... the name is the *conditional* operator

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud That may be true, but they are separate operators in the language spec. The subtraction operator might be syntactic sugar for a negation and an addition, but if so, would you call it the addition operator? (And the spec does mention "ternary operator" as an alternate name for the conditional operator.)

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud `?:` and `??` don't abide by the same rules. Inside `void Main()`, `Main ?? default(Action)` is a compile-time error, but `true ? Main : default(Action)` is perfectly valid. Even simpler, `1 ?? 2` is invalid, but `true ? 1 : 2` is valid. And `true ? new int?(1) : 2` has type `int?`, but `new int?(1) ?? 2` has type `int`.

Comment: So is it safe to assume that there is no built in way to achieve this? You just have to check for null?

Comment: @MattVaughan, did the modified line of code I provided not work for you?

Answer (score 1):

As of [C# 9.0](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-c-9-0/#target-typed--and-), this will finally be possible:

> #### Target typed ?? and ?:
>
> Sometimes conditional ?? and ?: expressions don’t have an obvious shared type between the branches. Such cases fail today, but C# 9.0 will allow them if there’s a target type that both branches convert to:
>
> ```
> Person person = student ?? customer; // Shared base type
> int? result = b ? 0 : null; // nullable value type
> ```

That means the code block in the question will also compile without errors; it will 'see' that `FieldInfo` and `PropertyInfo` have a shared base type, `MemberInfo`.

```
MemberInfo info = type.GetField(memberName) ?? type.GetProperty(memberName);
```

Answer (score -1):

As much as I like reflection (pun intended), here's an alternate approach using a delegate property. No need to throw an exception since this ensures the existence of the delegate member.

```
    private void SortByProperty<T>(List<T> list, Func<T, object> property, bool ascending)
    {
        Comparison<T> asc = (t1, t2) => ((IComparable)property.Invoke(t1)).CompareTo(property.Invoke(t2));
        Comparison<T> desc = (t1, t2) => ((IComparable)property.Invoke(t2)).CompareTo(property.Invoke(t1));

        list.Sort(ascending ? asc : desc);
    }
```